# Рow to set dynamic header using BIRT?

Tags: birt, lms, sap-successfactors

I don't know how to have a dynamic header within BIRT, I've tried crosstab but it does only shows in PDF and did not show in the `csv` report. Can I download the reports as an `xlsx` extension, will that solve the issue if it is downloaded through `xlsx` instead of `csv`?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think BIRT does not support CSV output.
A possible workaround is to code the CSV export yourself (see
https://github.com/eclipse/birt/discussions/1023).